# why is the datagridview cell click event showing the image of the first row after filtering?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

am using the `datagridview_cellClick` event to display the records of the row when clicked which works fine. But the problem is after a search to a specific row,once clicked to view records of that row, the image column shows the first image of the first row. Though the rest of the records of that row are displayed except for the image. In other words correct details like **name**, **Date of Birth**, etc show except for the image. Image shown is for the first row not for that particular row when clicked after search

Here's code for `CellClick` event

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        string query = "select spn_code,First_Name,Last_Name,Middle_Name,Date_Of_Birth,[Gender],[School],[Village],[Siblings],[Guardian],Contact_1,Contact_2,[Level],Life_Centre,Entry_Date,[Photo] from Child_Care_T1";
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
            return;

        this.lbl_spn.Text = "SPN CODE: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["spn_code"].Value.ToString();
       try
       {
           if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Photo"]))
            {
                // bytes = (byte[])r["Photo"];
                byte[] mydata = (byte[])dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Photo"];
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
                this.pictureBox_AD.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please click on Rows with data to view on side bar");
        }


        // MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
        //this.pictureBox_AD.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        this.lbl_fname.Text ="First Name: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["First_Name"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_lname.Text ="Last Name: "+ this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Last_Name"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_mname.Text ="Middle Name: "+ this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Middle_Name"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_DOB.Text ="Date Of Birth: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Date_Of_Birth"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_gender.Text ="Gender: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Gender"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_school.Text ="School: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["School"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_villge.Text ="Village: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Village"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_siblings.Text ="No. of Siblings: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Siblings"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_guardian.Text ="Guardian: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Guardian"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_contact1.Text ="Guardian Contact 1: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Contact_1"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_contact2.Text = "Guardian Contact 2: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Contact_2"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_level.Text = "Level: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Level"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_life_centre.Text = "Life Centre: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Life_Centre"].Value.ToString();
        this.lbl_entryDate.Text ="Entry Date: " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Entry_Date"].Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

Here's code for the search

```
private void txt_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView DatVlname = new DataView(dt);
        DatVlname.RowFilter = string.Format("[Last_Name] like '%{0}%' OR [First_Name] like '%{0}%' OR Life_Centre like '%{0}%' OR [Level] like '%{0}%'", txt_search.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DatVlname;
    }
```

Here's code for form load

```
 private void All_Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_search.Focus();

       // AddCheckBoxforDataGridView();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = "select Details_Number,spn_code,First_Name,Last_Name,Middle_Name,Date_Of_Birth,[Gender],[School],[Village],[Siblings],[Guardian],Contact_1,Contact_2,[Level],Life_Centre,Entry_Date,[Photo] from Child_Care_T1";
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

            da.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Load Data" + ex);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

`

Comment: Well, what happens when you clear the image before trying to load the new one? Do you ever hit the if clause, where you load the image?

Comment: how do you do that

Comment: `this.pictureBox_AD.Image = null` before the `try` in the `CellClick`